# NetSuite:I want to edit a savedSearch and saved it.But the filters of the savedSearch is null

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

The suitescript 1.0 code as follow:

```
function clientFieldChanged(type, name, linenum) {
if (name == 'class') {
    var brand_id = nlapiGetFieldValue('class');
    if (brand_id) {
        console.log(brand_id);
        var itemSearch = nlapiLoadSearch(null,'customsearch_item_brand_search');
        var itemSearchFilter = new nlobjSearchFilter('custitem30', null, 'anyof',brand_id);
        var filters = [itemSearchFilter];
        itemSearch.setFilters(filters);
        itemSearch.saveSearch();
    }
}
```

}
But after this script is executed,the filters of the saved search is null.[SuiteScript 1.0 saved Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ect7i.png)

The suitescript 2.0 code as follow:

```
function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {
    if(scriptContext.fieldId == 'class'){
        var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        var brand_id = currentRecord.getValue({fieldId:'class'});
        if(brand_id){
            var itemSearch = search.load({
                id: 'customsearch_item_brand_search'
            });
            var itemSearchFilter = search.createFilter({
                name:'custitem30',
                operator:search.Operator.ANYOF,
                values:brand_id
            });
            var filtersArray = [itemSearchFilter];
            itemSearch.filters = filtersArray;
            itemSearch.save();
        }
    }
}
```

After this script is executed,the filters of the saved search is right.[SuiteScript 2.0 saved Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdvQP.png)

What can I do to make the SuiteScript 1.0 saved Search same as the SuiteScript 2.0 saved Search?

By the way,nlapiRefreshLineItems is the api of suitescript 1.0,but there is no equivalent in version 2.0.If I want refresh item only in suitescript 2.0,how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In the 1.0 code change `setFilters()` to `addFilters()` so your code should be:

```
function clientFieldChanged(type, name, linenum) {
    if (name == 'class') {
        var brand_id = nlapiGetFieldValue('class');
        if (brand_id) {
            console.log(brand_id);
            var itemSearch = nlapiLoadSearch(null,'customsearch_item_brand_search');
            var itemSearchFilter = new nlobjSearchFilter('custitem30', null, 'anyof',brand_id);
            var filters = [itemSearchFilter];
            itemSearch.addFilters(filters);
            itemSearch.saveSearch();
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me, while the `setFilters` threw an error.

Comment: The api document abount addFilters said  "Adds a search filter list. Note that existing filters on the search are not changed".But I want to override the filters,the addFilters can not do it.

Comment: The 1.0 script works well in my environment.Can you show the screenshots about the error?

Comment: @GeorgeHuang I actually tried again and can't reproduce the error. But it works fine for me now what do yo above. Does the console.log() you have inside the if output anything? I mean are you 100% sure you enter the if?

If you run this code in the debugger, you should get an error or it should work, it's really strange if you are stuck in between the two..

Comment: Yes,I am sure the script enter the if.I can see the value of brand_id in the browser console.Have you tried to see the filters of the saved search after the script was run?The addFilters does not work,the filters is still null in my environment.I am confused.

Comment: @GeorgeHuang yeah I have, they work fine for me.. super strange. For me it adds the filters..

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

1. Load the search
2. Get the type/columns/filters
3. Modify the filters
4. Create another search
5. Use the previous config

That should work.